# Plugging in a USB dialup modem causes my Win7 computer to crash with a blue screen

Tags: windows-7, bsod

My computer runs Windows 7. I'm using a USB external modem to connect to dialup Internet. Once I connect the modem, Windows displays a blue screen (which is famous in Windows Vista). It says something like "dump physical memory." What can I do to use my modem?

Comment: StackOverflow.com is focused on programming questions.  You should ask this question on SuperUser.com. Good luck!

Comment: Try connecting the modem using a USB hub.

Answer (score 0):

Type "solutions" in the start menu to visit **View solutions to problems**. See what Windows itself says about the problem, the probable cause, and possible solutions.